# ajax xhr lengthComputable return false with php file

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

i'm doing an ajax request with a XMLHttpRequest in order to show the progress of the request. It's working great with an html file but evt.lengthComputable return false with a php file.

My php file is encoded in utf-8 and contain nothing special.

```
                xhr: function()
            {

              console.log('xhr');
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


              xhr.addEventListener('loadend', uploadComplete, false);
              function uploadComplete(event) {
                  console.log('uploadComplete');
                  //do stuff
              }


              //Download progress
              xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                console.log([evt.lengthComputable, evt.loaded, evt.total]);
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                  var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;


                }
              }, false);
              return xhr;
            }
```

Thanx for helping :) !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because php file are dynamic, you need to set a correct Content-Length header:

```
<?
ob_start();
/* your code here */

$length = ob_get_length();
header('Content-Length: '.$length."\r\n");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'."\r\n");
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Always use these lines at the end of your php script to correctly determine the length and outputting the htmls and data  if any
$length = ob_get_length();
header('Content-Length: '.$length."\r\n");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'."\r\n");
ob_end_flush();