# lengthComputable is always false

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, http

I've spent an entire day on this... trying and doing research but I couldn't find the right solution for this specific case. I'm doing a very simple task: AJAX HTTP download request with a progress status bar via HTML 5. But lengthComputable is always false, and I can't figure out why!

I have simplified all the code to make it readable:

This is the JavaScript code:

```
var http = new Object();

http.request = function (){

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);

    function updateProgress(a){
        console.log(a.lengthComputable)
        if (a.lengthComputable) {
            console.log(a.loaded/a.total*100);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST",'http://www.name.com/test/test.php',true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

      if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            console.log(response);
        }

      }
    xmlhttp.send();

}

http.request();
```

This is the PHP code:

```
ob_start();

$i=0;
$txt='';
while($i<(1024*1024)){
    $txt.=rand(0, 9);
    ++$i;
}

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($txt));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

echo $txt;

ob_end_flush();
```

I'think this is a server-side problem, maybe some setting that I don't know about Apache / PHP, but this is just a feeling of who doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Does `xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener("progress", ...` work?

Comment: yes, it outputs false from 15 to 19 times...I guess it depends on the internet speed

Comment: Some updates about this topic? I am having the same problem but with jquery :( @BillyBelly

Comment: Having same problem (also with jquery).

Comment: Maybe try `ob_get_length()` for  php Content-Length calculation...? 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034312/ajax-xhr-lengthcomputable-return-false-with-php-file

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$pack = true;
if (empty($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]) || strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"], 'gzip') === false) {
    $pack = false;
}




// checks if gzip is supported by client
$response = json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);


// if supported, gzips data
$replyBody = '';
if ($pack) {
    //header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
    $replyBody = gzencode($response, 9, FORCE_GZIP);

    header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($replyBody));
}
//header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: gzip");


echo $response;
```

Comment: You should provide description of what you doing. . [check how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)