# Download PDF file With FTP using XMLHttpRequest and generic handler

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to download PDF file from FTP server with Jquery Ajax request. I referred http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/.

My Jquery ajax call is as below

```js
 $.ajax({
                 xhr: function () {
                     var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                   
                     //Download progress
                     xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                         console.log("Event :"+evt.lengthComputable);
                         if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                             var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                             //Do something with download progress
                             console.log(percentComplete);
                         }
                     }, false);
                     return xhr;
                 },
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: "Downloader.ashx",
             
                 success: function (data) {
                     //Do something success-ish
                 }
             });
```

And My C# generic handler code to download file is as below

```js
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            DownLoadFilesFromFTp("MyFile.pdf", "Foldername");
            
        }
        public bool DownLoadFilesFromFTp(string fileName,string ftpFolder)
        {
            //Create FTP Request.
            try
            {
                string Ftp_Host = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ftp_Host"];
                string Ftp_UserName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ftp_UserName"];
                string Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
                string downloadpath= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["downloadpath"];
                //Fetch the Response and read it into a MemoryStream object.
                string ftpurl = Ftp_Host + ftpFolder + "/" + fileName;
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpurl));
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Ftp_UserName, Password);
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Proxy = null;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = false;

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                FileStream writeStream = null;
                //if (fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 3, 3) == "pdf" || fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 3, 3) == "PDF")
                //{
                writeStream = new FileStream(downloadpath + fileName, FileMode.Create);


                //}
                int Length = 2048;  // 2048;

                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
                int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                }


                responseStream.Close();
                writeStream.Close();
                response.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (WebException wEx)
            {
                return false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;

            }
        }
```

When I run a code files downloads to a folder without any issues and on Ajax call
 **if (evt.lengthComputable) {

  }**
When I console evt i got below result
[image]
Always returns false so i am unable to track a progress.

1) is there anything wrong with the code ?
2) Any alternative way to show progress bar while downloading pdf

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034312/ajax-xhr-lengthcomputable-return-false-with-php-file

Your downloader needs to output `Content-length` header. Logically, how can you know the percent downloaded if you do not know the total file size?

Comment: The generic handler C# code downloads the file to the local directory without any issues. only thing is to show a Progress bar while downloading.

Comment: You should serve the file with a content-length. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362419/how-to-stream-file-from-disk-to-client-browser-in-net-mvc and adapt your code

Comment: have you searched the internet or come across this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519290/downloading-files-using-ftpwebrequest

Answer (score 3):

For the **bytes uploaded**, it is quite easy to show progress bar. Just monitor the `xhr.upload.onprogress` event. The browser knows the size of the files it has to upload and the *size of the uploaded data*, so it can provide the progress info.

For the **bytes downloaded**, it is a little bit more difficult, because the only thing that the browser knows in this case is the size of the bytes it is receiving.

> The reason of `evt.lengthComputable` is `0` is that the browser doesn't
>   know how many bytes will be sent in the server request.

There is a solution for this, it's sufficient to set a **Content-Length header** on the server like below, in order to get the total size of the bytes the browser is going to receive.

```
// prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
// Add Content-Length of the file to headers
// if the headers is not set then the evt.loaded will be 0
resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", "lengthOfYourFile");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code JS side look fine.
I am not C# programmer, but i observed that C# server side, download the file ftp and save it to disk server, but never response/send the PDF binary to JS SIDE?
From JS side is 0 bytes download. and evt.lengthComputable is alway false/0.